# Dynamic exposed filters in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-exposed-filter

I've got a question in drupal. I have two filters. The values of the 2nd filter depends on what value was chosen in the first filter.
Example.
First filter values : `Lakers,Clippers`
Second filter values : if Lakers was chosen = `KOBE,GASOL`
                       if Clippers was chosen = `PAUL,GRIFFIN` .

Is there any module that supports this? Or do I have to code this? If I do is there any reference or guide that I could read and follow?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is
Drupal has a module called hierarchical select.

check this out 
https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: is this also possible to use in exposed filters?

Comment: Yes if you mean you want to use it in views exposed filter. you need to create the view with the filters exposed and select 'hierarchical select' as selection type. You can go through this link. https://drupal.org/node/720268.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hierachical select. It is chock full of bugs and since the maintainer went to work for Acquia, he no longer pays any attention to it. You'll have to write some code to make this work using contextual filters.